# Bona Fide meaning?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage

I was learning about the word "bona fide" and I came across many definitions, some said, it means genuine/not fake, some websites said it means done in good faith.

If I use bona fide in describing someone like "bona fide american" what would the bona fide here mean? What would be an appropriate choice here, saying "bona fide american" or "authentic american"?

Comment: Yeah, those two definitions are basically the same.  You'd say that somewhat made a "bona fide" offer to buy your house - which means an offer made in good faith - which just means a real offer rather than one that the buyer will withdraw (i.e. a fake offer).  If you ever have to attest to the genuineness of an American, a position that I don't wish upon you, I think "bona fide" and "authentic" would both do the job and convey the same meaning.

Comment: Quidquid latine dictum sit, altum sonatur.